# PeopleSoft - writing a report that continually looks back 7 days when run on recurrence

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm trying to write a query in Query Manager that I intend to put on a recurrence. Right now, I have a field that is using the DATEADD sql code and it works well for my needs.

The problem is, this is a new hire report and I want it to look back 7 days every time it's run. I would think the code would be something like this:

DATEADD(DAY, -7, Current Date (EffSeq = Last))

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to input it properly into the criteria so that the report will run properly.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally stumbled upon the answer - which is similar to Robin's, but slightly different:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could you clarify your question?

Do you want the effective date check to use instead of sysdate, sysdate-7 ?

If this is the case you can change teh criteria from using 'Current Date' to 'Expression' with expression 'sysdate -7' (if you are on an Oracle DB)

[image]

Comment: I  think you are correct - I want the effective date of the report to be the current date minus 7 days. I tried your suggestion and I got an error: "A SQL error occurred. Please consult your system log for details.
Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=8010, Message=[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'SYSDATE'. (50,380)"